# How do I test Sentry tags that are sent from a Django app exception?

Tags: python, django, testing, sentry

Our Django application is configured to send all `logger.error`s and `logger.exception`s to Sentry. I'm trying to implement something where in *some* cases, I can assign a custom tag to the event in question before the exception hits and have that event be tagged appropriately. Since I'm using it in more than one place, I want to make a function like this:

```py
from sentry_sdk import push_scope

def set_sentry_custom_tag(key: str, value: str) -> None:
    with push_scope() as scope:
        scope.set_tag(key, value)
        logger.info(f'Set sentry custom tag -> {key}:{value}')
```

...and use it like so:

```py
try:
    check_widget_factory()
except Exception as e:
    set_sentry_custom_tag('my-tag-key', 'my-tag-value')
    logger.exception(f'Widget check failed: {e}')
```

I *think* this will work but not sure if the `push_scope` needs to be directly in the method where the exception happens-- I'm a little fuzzy on how the `Scope` works for Sentry and if it is in some context in the immediate frame before getting passed on to the logger handling which sends the event to Sentry.

I'm trying to write some tests to ensure that this tag is set appropriately and attached to the event when an exception is raised, but coming up empty so far as to how to get the local scope and verify that the tag is set. I can modify the function to return the scope and then examine it like that, but ideally that's not how it's going to behave in production. I need something along the lines of this:

```py
def test_set_sentry_custom_tag(self):
    set_sentry_custom_tag(key='test-key', value='test-value')
    scope = find_the_current_scope_somehow()
    self.assertIn('test-key', scope._tags.keys())
    self.assertEqual(scope._tags['test-key'], 'test-value')
```

Anyone done some custom tagging in Sentry for cases like this, and can share how testing was done?

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly I believe your last example is not a particularly useful unit test. I would much rather mock `check_widget_factory()` to throw an exception and assert that an event got sent through. To do that, consider this:

```
events = []
init(transport=events.append)
# <mock check_widget_factory() here>

# call your try-except code here

assert events[0]['tags']['my-tag-key'] == 'my-tag-value'
```

This is not significantly slower than checking whether setting the tag actually set the tag and does not rely on private APIs in the SDK.